# Unable to understand the classpath in java

Tags: java, classpath

I am having hard time understanding the concept of classpath even though after going through oracle document.Please help me out in this.

I have following directory structure

```
Sample
|
-----source
|       |
|       src
|        |
|       Test2.java
|
------classes
        |
       com
        |
       Test1.java
```

the source code are as follows

Test1.java

```
package classes.com;

public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("In file Test1 in com package....");
    }
}
```

Test2.java

```
package source.src;

public class Test2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test1 test=new Test1();
        System.out.println("In class src..Test2...");
    }
}
```

I compiled Test1.java as

```
Q:\Sample>javac classes\com\Test1.java
```

and it works fine

Now since Test2.java has dependency on Test1.java so i am suing the below command

```
javac -classpath classes\com source\src\Test2.java
```

however its failing stating unable to find class Test1.

Not sure what i am doing wrong.Need Help

Comment: A `.java` file is probably a source file, not a compiled file (`.class`)

Comment: Yes i am trying to compile Test2.java which as a dependency on Test1.java which is in another package

Comment: `classes` should serve as the output directory for the compiler, you specify it with the `-d` option. Then in the second run you specify it as `-classpath` as well. And you don't specify the subdirs corresponding to package name segments.

Comment: yes i understand the classes directory should be used for .class file however right now i am trying to understand how to get this thing working

Comment: For starters, don't treat that directory as a package name. Also, classpath is not used to enumerate all the packages you depend on. A single classpath entry covers all packages present under that root.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the wrong structure, you need to set the classpath to the top level folder where it contains the full package name (`classes/com/Test1.java`), i.e.:

```
javac -classpath . source\src\Test2.java
```

where `.` is pointing to the current folder which is the folder that contains `classes` folder.

---

Also, you forgot to include the import statement:

```
import classes.com.Test1;
```

Comment: does . represent a current directory?

Comment: @beginner_developer Yes, `Sample` folder.

Comment: It worked Thanks a lot.So I have to understand if we are using . which means the current directory the compiler goes to the sub-directory to find the file ?if yes then why it was not working earlier when i was specifying the path to Test1 class file (classes/com) in classpath

Comment: @beginner_developer You need to specify the folder that contains the first part of the package. E.g. the package is `com.foo.bar`, then you need to include the folder that contains `com` folder.

Comment: my package start with classes.shouldnt it be classes or its different concept

Comment: Your package should not start with "classes". That should be the name of the classpath root directory and not the name of a package.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your source files are not organized properly.
Keep all your .java files under your source directory and have the "classes" or "build" directory to store the .class files.

When running your applications make sure the "classes" or "build" directory is added as a classpath.

The root directory where your classes are stored should be set as "classpath". In your case "classes" directory is the root folder.